# Remove a value from a dictionary inside a dictionary but keep the key

Tags: python

For example, I have this:

```
dict[sth] = {'key1'=value, 'key2'={'key1'=value,'key2'=value}, 'key3'=value}
```

becomes:

```
dict[sth] = {'key1'=value, 'key2'={'key1'='','key2'=value}, 'key3'=value}
```

I don't know if these has to be known but all the values entered are user inputs.

Comment: Just replace the value? `d[key][inner_key] = ''`

Comment: Thanks it worked @C.Nivs appreciate it m8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't "remove" the value without the key, but you can replace it with empty string.

go to the instance 'key_2' that its a nested dictionary, and go to 'key_1' of the nested dict by:

```
dict['key_2']['key_1'] =''
```

and that's it... good luck :)